# Disable VS Code Output Window (not Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I keep the output window from displaying in VS Code? I don't need it and it takes up a lot of screen real estate.  I don't see any options in preferences and can't find anything to help with it.

Comment: I've found this bug report, but apparently it is low priority: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22653

For now, I just press Ctrl+K,H to hide the output when it pops out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please note that the content in this answer applies only to those whom are using Visual Studio Code's [Task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) feature. If you aren't using said feature, this answer will likely not be of any use to you.

When you configure your task, you are given the ability to configure whether or not the task's output is shown [in Visual Studio Code]. This is done with the [`"showOutput"` property](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_output-window-behavior) in your task configuration.

If you want to disable the task's output from being shown, you can set the `"showOutput"` property to `never` in your task's configuration. This will prevent anything from being written to the output window, thus preventing the window from being shown.

An example task configuration, with the showing of output disabled:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "echo",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["Hello World"],
    "showOutput": "never"
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help. And yes, as your edit stated, it should be `"never"` instead of `"false"`, my apologies.

Comment: Works great. Note that this is now deprecated and replaced by `"presentation" : { "reveal": "..." }`. I would recommend using `silent` as that will hide the output unless there is an error.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_output-behavior

Answer (score 36):

*edit: this answer is probably outdated, follow the other answers on this page*

If you want to disable the output window opening on its own:

You will have to open it from `View > Output`.

You can add the following line to your user settings:

```
"debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
```

Comment: This does not solve it for me and my install is fairly generic as per extensions. As of writing I am using version 1.74.3.

Answer (score 11):

You can also click on the top boundary of output window, you will get a vertical resize pointer, and then just drag it down. This will permanently takes away output window.

And in future if you need output window, you can open it via view->Output

Comment: this also minimizes the terminal window.

Comment: Perfect! This worked. Exactly what I was looking for Thanks.

Comment: This no longer works

Answer (score 10):

Right click on the output bar and unmark the output option.

Comment: It still opens by it's own

Comment: It keeps on popping back up every time I click on a file

Answer (score 4):

Right click on output bar and click reset location. This will restore your Terminal window to its original size, if you need a Terminal open while developing.

My problem: I had my Terminal open, then clicked something that caused the Output window to open next to the Terminal. By clicking 'reset location' (after right clicking output bar), the Output window is closed and restores the Terminal window to its original size.

Comment: This worked.  It's a weird UI paradigm (setting location) to toggle between I guess.. splitting terminal "area" vs leaving it as a tab.  Perhaps a menu option to revert to tabbed?

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me. Noticed the output window was always opening with the dropdown set to "react-native", so I uninstalled the React Native Tools extension and it solved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

In jupyter-Notebook(vscode version), you can click on a cell and then press "o", it will hide the cell output.

Answer (score -1):

the best way i think is to right click to "output" on the panel and un click the output option
this will take away the output function only and leave the terminal intact
and if you would like to manually bring it back just type "Crt+shift+

Comment: It is still opening on it's own

Answer (score -2):

As of vs code version 1.63.1:

Click the settings icon in the lower left-hand corner of the window.

Go to Settings.

The User setting will be auto focused.

Go to User > Features > Output.

Correction:
The out-of-control output for me stems from the jsHint extension. I disabled the extension and reloaded VScode. And now I have No more unwanted output.

Choose the setting you want. Save. Done.